# JWTValidationException - utf-8’ codec can’t decode bytes

Tags: python, okta

I got the following error on python when access_token is passed to “verify_access_token”. Does anyone know how to fix this error? I used "okta-jwt-verifier 0.2.3"

from okta_jwt_verifier import JWTVerifier

```
def authenticate(self, request):
    access_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    jwt_verifier = JWTVerifier(issuer='https://devtest.okta.com/oauth2/default', 
    client_id='12345', audience='api://default')
    loop.run_until_complete(jwt_verifier.verify_access_token(access_token))
```

**ERROR**

**JWTValidationException
Invalid header string: ‘utf-8’ codec can’t decode bytes in position 1-2: invalid continuation byte**

Request Method: GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/getdata/ Django Version:  2.2.10 Exception Type:  JWTValidationException Exception Value: Invalid header string: ‘utf-8’ codec can’t decode bytes in position 1-2: invalid continuation byte Exception Location:  C:\WEB\project\pyenv\lib\site-packages\okta_jwt_verifier\jwt_verifier.py in verify_access_token, line 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem after sharing this question with OKTA dev team as per following:

Word of “Bearer” needs to be removed if access_token object has it. This can be done through a string replacement as below the line.

access_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', '').replace('Bearer', '').strip()